# Sorting datetime objects while ignoring the year?

Tags: python, datetime, sorting

I have a list of birthdays stored in [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects. How would one go about sorting these in Python using only the `month` and `day` arguments?

For example,

```
[
    datetime.datetime(1983, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    datetime.datetime(1996, 1, 13, 0 ,0)
    datetime.datetime(1976, 2, 6, 0, 0)
    ...
]
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `month` and `day` to create a value that can be used for sorting:

```
birthdays.sort(key = lambda d: (d.month, d.day))
```

Answer (score 7):

```
l.sort(key = lambda x: x.timetuple()[1:3])
```

Comment: BTW: I'm assuming that list is meant to be datetime objects (as mentioned in the first part of your question), and not strings (as shown in the code snippet).

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I changed the example to reflect what I meant to do. :)

Answer (score 3):

If the dates are stored as strings—you say they aren't, although it looks like they are—you might use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)'s parser:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> bd = ['February 6, 1976','January 13, 1996','January 1, 1983']
>>> bd = [parse(i) for i in bd]
>>> pprint(bd)
[datetime.datetime(1976, 2, 6, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(1996, 1, 13, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(1983, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
>>> bd.sort(key = lambda d: (d.month, d.day)) # from sth's answer
>>> pprint(bd)
[datetime.datetime(1983, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1996, 1, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1976, 2, 6, 0, 0)]
```

If your dates are in different formats, you might give fuzzy parsing a shot:

```
>>> bd = [parse(i,fuzzy=True) for i in bd] # replace line 4 above with this line
```